# Colobar_position_label, Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to label my colorbar and set its position horzontal.

```
 Min=0.8;       
 Max=12;
 h=colorbar;        
 set(h,'YTickLabel',{num2str(Min),num2str(Max)})
```

it works fine.But for horizontal bar it is strange.

```
 h = colorbar('horiz');       
 set(h,'location','southoutside')
 set(h,'YTickLabel',{num2str(Min),num2str(Max)})
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the final line to

```
set(h,'XTickLabel',{num2str(Min),num2str(Max)})
```

(i.e. `XTickLabel` instead of `YTickLabel`).